# jQuery autocomplete select not triggered

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jQuery `jquery-1.10.2` and jQuery ui `1.11.4`

Here is the autocomplete function :

```
$("#txtPOI").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url("crowd/get_POIs") ?>',
            data: {cat: selectedCode, q: request.term},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "post",
            success: function(data) {

                response( $.map( data, function( item )
                {
                    return{
                            label: item.title,
                            value: item.title,
                            contentid: item.contentid,
                            latitude: item.latitude,
                            longitude: item.longitude
                        }
                }));

            },
            fail : function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $("#txtPOI").val(ui.item.latitude);
                alert('selected');
                /*
                alert(ui.item.contentid);
                log( ui.item ?
                  "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                  "Nothing selected, input was " + this.title);
                alert(ui.item.value);
                */
            },
            open: function(event, ui) {
                $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
            },
            minLength: 3

        });
    }
});
```

The ajax response successfully returned data from database. However when I tried to do something inside the `select` nothing happened, it seems that the `select` is not triggered. I would like to get the value of `ui.item.contentid` as well as `ui.item.latitude` and `ui.item.longitude` upon the selection of the autocomplete item.

Why the `select` event is not triggered ? How to solve this issue ?

Comment: try to remove the $("#txtPOI").val(ui.item.latitude); and test if you get the alert working

Comment: it's not working. there is no error shown on browser debugger as well

Comment: can you provide some html and the url of ajax so that i can help you

Comment: check @Neeraj Verma answer

Comment: Yeah. it's working now. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select is option for autocomplete object not for Ajax object.

Try this:

```js
$("#txtPOI").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url("crowd/get_POIs") ?>',
            data: {cat: selectedCode, q: request.term},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "post",
            success: function(data) {

                response( $.map( data, function( item )
                {
                    return{
                            label: item.title,
                            value: item.title,
                            contentid: item.contentid,
                            latitude: item.latitude,
                            longitude: item.longitude
                        }
                }));

            },
            fail : function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function( event ) {
         // do what ever you want to do...
    }
});
```

Comment: I got my mistake now. Thank you very much for your help. it's working now